# Multiply Cells that are not blank

Tags: excel, vba

I need to multiply the QTYs in column B by the values in the other columns if they are not blank, row by row like this: ($B3*Row,Col). I know I can do this with VBA, but I can't get a method going that will multiply and check blank cells. The last row just sums up numbers in each column. I tried making a function and putting it in a sub, but I had no luck. I've attached a picture.
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: do you want to multiply them in order of the column or sum up the columns and then multiply, `B3 * C3*D3*...` or `B3 * sum(C3:AE3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT()` should do what you want. Example for first summed column

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C6:C24,$B6:$B24)
```

Then just fill right from there. It ignores blank cells.

Comment: Geez. Yeah that works. I overthought the crap out of this. Thank you!